# PHP (5.5) - database search with MySQLi - getting datalist but no output

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm just learning how to do this so please forgive my ignorance!

Here is my test site: http://webtestkit.com/1KaraokeDJ/index.php

First, I found this code in a learning example and that code worked just fine. (http://www.mostlikers.com/2013/08/search-engine.html) - no problems. I even made the sample database and checked all was working.

now I wanted to change it to work for my purpose (a karaoke search)...

here is my code:

```
<?php
  include("connect.php");
  session_start();
  if(isset($_POST['submit']))
  {
    $search=$_POST['search'];
    $_SESSION['title']= $search;
    if(($_SESSION['title'])!="")
      { header("location:index.php"); }
    else
      { echo "<script> alert('Please enter something to search for') </script>"; }
  }
?>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>1KaraokeDJ.com</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="login">
      <form method="post">
        <p><img src="top.jpg" /></p>
        <p>
          <?php if(isset($_SESSION['title'])) { ?>
            <input name="search" type="search" list="searchkey" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['title'];?>" class="search" />
          <?php } else { ?>
            <input name="search" type="search" list="searchkey" placeholder="Just type your text here and press enter - ex : Abba"  class="search" />
          <?php } ?>
        </p>
        <datalist id="searchkey">
          <?php
            $tile=$db->query("SELECT * FROM `1KaraokeDJ.com`");
            while($storetitle=mysqli_fetch_object($tile))
          { ?>
            <option  value="<?php echo $storetitle->title ?>">
          <?php } ?>
        </datalist>
        <p><input type="submit" name="submit" id="click" class="searchbutton" value="Karaoke Search"  /></p> 
        <?php if(isset($_SESSION['title'])) {
          if(($_SESSION['title']!=""))
          {
            $data=$_SESSION['title'];
            $view=$db->query("select * from 1KaraokeDJ.com where title like '%$data%' limit 10");
            $check=mysqli_num_rows($view);
            if($check!="")
            {
              while($descri=mysqli_fetch_object($view))
            {
          ?>
        <div class="reslt">
          <h3 id="resuil-title"><?php echo $descri->title; ?></h3>
          <p class="Description">
            <?php $description = str_replace($data, '<span class="highlight">'.$data."</span>", $descri->artist);
            echo $description; ?>
          <p>
          <hr>
        </div>
        <?php } } else { ?>
          <div class="reslt">
            <h3 id="resuil-title">Nothing fond!</h3>
            <p class="Description">Try changing your search terms<p><hr>
          </div>
        <?php } } } ?>
      </form>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The search field is finding data in the dropdown list so the connection is fine and the search works.

I think I understand most of the code, but I don't seem to understand this:

```
$view=$db->query("select * from 1KaraokeDJ.com where title like '%$data%' limit 10");
$check=mysqli_num_rows($view);
if($check!="")
{ while($descri=mysqli_fetch_object($view)) {
```

My If always goes to else "Nothing Found"

Any help? The way I learn is by doing - so it's trial and error until I figure it out!

Comment: Your query failed and you need to find out why. check for errors http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php  and apply it to your query.

Comment: Try escaping the table name like `1KaraokeDJ.com (can't close the back-tick but i hope you get the idea)

Comment: or change `if($check!="")` to `if($check > 0)` ..since `mysqli_num_row` would always return an integer.

Comment: `\`You can escape backticks in comments\`` @AlexTartan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your table `1KaraokeDJ.com` is interpreted as `DatabaseName.TableName`

To avoid this, escape your table name

```
Select * from `1KaraokeDJ.com` Where ...
```

Comment: got it - i just renamed my database and removed the .com
that seems to have fixed the issue right there.